# Show that $\frac{\sqrt[n]a}{\sqrt[n]{ab}+\sqrt[n]a+1}+\frac{\sqrt[n]b}{\sqrt[n]{bc}+\sqrt[n]b+1}+\frac{\sqrt[n]c}{\sqrt[n]{ac}+\sqrt[n]c+1}=1$

Tags: arithmetic

If $$\sqrt[n]{{abc}} = 1,$$
Prove that $$\frac{\sqrt[n]a}{\sqrt[n]{ab}+\sqrt[n]a+1}+\frac{\sqrt[n]b}{\sqrt[n]{bc}+\sqrt[n]b+1}+\frac{\sqrt[n]c}{\sqrt[n]{ac}+\sqrt[n]c+1}=1.$$

Comment: First of all note that you can simply ignore all those $\sqrt[n]\cdot$. But why the tag *diophantine-equations*?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569322/simplyfying-the-equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x = \sqrt[n]a, y = \sqrt[n]b, z = \sqrt[n]c$.  Then you have $xyz = 1$ and 
$$\frac{x}{xy+x+1}+\frac{y}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z}{zx+z+1} = \frac{x}{xy+x+1}+\frac{xy}{1+xy+x}+\frac{1}{x+1+xy}$$

where we multiplied the second term's numerator and denominator by $x$ and the third term's by $xy$.

Comment: Brilliantly done :)

Comment: Thanks.  Hagen's comment helped...

Comment: Thanks a lot Hagen and macavity.

Comment: I trust you can finish that off ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm really sorry. I wrote that I was confused, but a mistake in my writing. So I thought to myself this is the result.